# Hangouts Chat Bot only working for Apps Scripts owner and not others in gSuite organization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts

Edit: I believe I solved this - after auth, the user has to remove the bot from the room, and then re-add them in order to trigger onAddToSpace(e). I've filed an issue on Github to ask if this is expected behavior, or if I'm still doing something wrong.

I've created an Async Hangouts Chat Bot in Google Apps Scripts following the guide here: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script#async_messages

The bot works for me as the Apps Scripts file owner, but when someone else from the domain enters a space with the bot, it doesn't work - for example, it doesn't detect that the other user has added the bot to a space and as such onAddToSpace(e) does not execute. When I use method spaces.members.get, it only shows the space I share with the bot.

When my teammate invited the bot, there was a message that it required authorization and from there it went to the Apps Scripts authorization page. My teammate authorized the app/bot, but still nothing.

I have my Hangouts API configuration set as pictured below.

In my Apps Scripts file, I've used "deploy from manifest" and have ensured that I am using a versioned Deployment ID pasted in the Hangouts API. Do I need to publish this in some different way? Screenshot: [Apps scripts deployments from manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSxz8.png)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

[Hangouts API configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfDFN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the bot properly?, if you are using the HEAD as the deployment ID only people with both access to the code and the bot can use it, so either share the code or deploy another version (i'd recommend creating a developer version and a production version)

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty sure I deployed properly - in the apps script file I did publish > deploy from manifest and then grabbed the ID from a versioned deployment (I attached another screenshot) and pasted that into the Hangouts API. My fall-back was going to be to share the Apps Scripts file with everyone in the organization, but I'm hoping I don't need to do that. 

I also added a screenshot of the Hangouts API credentials (I added the OAuth 2.0 one more recently).

Do I need to do anything in the IAM section of the Cloud Console for this specific project? I am the only member and owner.